# zoom social icon on hover without affecting parent container height

Tags: css, sass

I have some social icons, want them to have a border and padding of 0.5rem and font size of 2.2rem, default font size is 2rem on mouse hover, without affecting parent div height. How to do that?
this is the default style

[image: Default Style]
[image: What I want]

here is the code for it

```
#g-footer .footer-b .social-links div a:hover {
    color: #40c2be;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #40c2be;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```
<div class="social-links">
<div><span>شبکه اجتماعی:</span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-telegram"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look here for the CSS zooming effect https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp

Comment: @Zeikman, thanks for the link, it words will when I don't want padding and border like you see in the image.

Comment: You are probably looking for scale, but could you make your code into a runnable snippet so we can be sure we are giving a workable solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fa:hover,
    .fa:active {
        color: red;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
        -o-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }

    .social-links {
        border: 1px solid purple;
        padding: 20px
    }

    .social-links i {
        padding: 0 5px
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="social-links">
        <div><span>شبکه اجتماعی:</span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i></a></div>
    </div>
```